# How can I combine multiple CSS rules?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
div#id_div_allposts {   
    width: 100%;    
}

div.class_div_post {
    width: 100%;
}

div.class_div_editdelete {
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can i write it in one line ?

And what's the way to select a html tag with id and class ?

Comment: Please take some time to read through [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) about selectors. It's not a difficult read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is separate them with a comma e.g

```css
div#id_div_allposts,
div.class_div_post,
div.class_div_editdelete {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#id_div_allposts, div.class_div_post, div.class_div_editdelete {
    width: 100%;
}
```

or assuming that you want all div to have width 100% then...

```
div{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div#id_div_allposts, div.class_div_post, div.class_div_editdelete {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can group multiple selectors in `CSS` via a comma.

**Note:** The comma starts an entirely new selector from the very start.

Answer (score 0):

Use the comma to separate multiple declarations

```
div#id_div_allposts, div.class_div_post, div.class_div_editdelete {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Selecting an html tag with and id and class would be

```
div#ID.class
```